# Need recommendations for front-end framework and cross-platform development

Tags: web-development, cross-platform, mobile, react, angular

We have a product (Webforms | ASP.Net | SQL Server) in production.
We're looking forward to rebuild it and thus using the newer JS Frameworks seems obvious.

As we're also planning to have a mobile app to go with the web version. Which would be the best tech stack to go ahead with?

I've discovered couple of options:

1. Angular for web, Flutter for Cross-platform Mobile app
2. React for web, React Native for Mobile app

Backend will remain being SQL Server for DB and .NET for APIs

Is there something that I'm missing, do highlight that as well.

Thanks.